# SyntaxError unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I am new to using Slim, and I keep receiving a syntax error when adding if conditions to the view. I added a instance method to the User model so I can run this condition in the view.

_conversation.html.slim:

```
- if user.paid?

- sender = conversation.last_sender
- message = conversation.last_message
- receipts = conversation.receipts.recipient(@user).is_unread
- is_unread = receipts.count > 0 ? true : false
.outer
  div.converation class="#{is_unread == true ? 'unread' : 'read'}" onclick="#" data-href="#{conversation_path(conversation)}"
    .col_1
      img alt="" src="#{is_unread == true ? '/assets/un_read.png' : '/assets/read.png'}" /
      span.conversation_avatar
        =link_to "/profile/#{sender.id}" do
          img alt="" src="#{sender.avatar.image_url(:avatar)}" /
      h5 = sender.username
      strong 
        = sender.age
        ', 
        = sender.gender
        ',
        = sender.sexuality
      small
        br
        = sender.location.city
        ',
        = sender.location.state
    .col_2
      span = message.subject
      p = message.body
    .col_3
      strong = extract_date(message.created_at)
      small = extract_time(message.created_at)
  form action="#" 
    fieldset
      input type="checkbox" class="conversation_checkbox"

- else

Text would go here
```

Comment: I thought with Slim you don't add an `end`

Comment: @Pavan You're wrong, stop giving advice on topics you're unsure of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indentation is very important in Slim. You haven't indented anything within your first line, `if user.paid?`; you need to do so, or you're producing an `if` statement with no body.